# Sorting MySQL table on a Field and sending output by separate emails in PHP for each sub-group under that field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following query in my code:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ENDT_NO = '0' ORDER BY SERVICED ASC");
```

Let's say there are 30 rows in total but 3 different type of 'SERVICED' field, i.e. AA, BB and CC.

Have tried various options to send emails for each 'SERVICED' category but the email goes only for the last category, i.e. CC.

My code goes as follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
     {
$serviced=$row['SERVICED'];
$message .= '
<body><tr>
<td>' .$row['polno'] . '</td>
<td>' .$row['umr'] . '</td>
</tr></body>';

$to="xx@abc.com";
$subject = 'Renewal List from ' . 'for ' . $serviced;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .=  'From: aa@xxx.com' . "\r\n" ;
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{ 
echo 'Your' . 'email has been sent successfully.' . '<br>';
} 
    }
```

Comment: you know that mysql_query is deprecated and was removed in the newer php version- Please update and swithc to pdo or mysqli.

Comment: ...many, many years ago

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a look into the data, on first shot I will assume that only rows with SERVICED="CC" will also have ENDT_NO='0'. That WHERE clause in the query is probably limiting your rows in a way you don't want.

P.S. That's a very old PHP code. You should consider moving to a newer version and rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

you should try fixing the query first to something like
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_that_you_need_1,column_that_you_need_2 SEPARATOR "|") email_content from business WHERE ENDT_NO = '0' GROUP BY SERVICED ORDER BY SERVICED ASC`

p.s: i'm not sure if you really need END_NO = '0'

but after you get the email_content you can use `explode` from php, e.g:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $temp[] = explode("|",$row['email_content'])
}

for ($i;$i<count($temp);$i++){
  //email every $temp[$i] that you need
}
```

cheers